# How to run a single service defined in a docker-compose yml and ignore errors of other services?

Tags: docker

This is my docker compose yaml file

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  dynamo:
    image: bazel/production/local/docker/dynamodb:dynamodb
    env_file: dynamodb/${ENV}.env
    ports:
      - 7070:7070
    volumes:
        - ${REPO}/production/local/docker/dynamodb/start_dynamo.sh:/home/dynamodblocal/start.sh
        - dynamo-data:/home/dynamodblocal
    entrypoint: ""
    command: /home/dynamodblocal/start.sh

  redis50_cluster:
    image: bazel/production/local/docker/redis50:redis50
    ports:
      - 6380:6380
      - 6381:6381
      - 6382:6382
    volumes:
      - ${REPO}/production/local/docker/redis50/entrypoint.sh:/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
      - ${REPO}/production/local/docker/redis50/redis-cluster-node0.conf:/etc/redis/redis-cluster-node0.conf
      - ${REPO}/production/local/docker/redis50/redis-cluster-node1.conf:/etc/redis/redis-cluster-node1.conf
      - ${REPO}/production/local/docker/redis50/redis-cluster-node2.conf:/etc/redis/redis-cluster-node2.conf
      - ${REPO}/production/local/docker/redis50/init_redis.sh:/usr/local/bin/init_redis.sh
      - ${REPO}/production/local/docker/redis50/check_redis.sh:/usr/local/bin/check_redis.sh
      - redis50-data:/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "check_redis.sh"]
      interval: 60s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 12
      start_period: 10s
```

I only want to start up the redis service, so I tried this command

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d redis50_cluster
```

however it failed because

```
ERROR: Couldn't find env file: /Users/antkong/work/production/local/docker/dynamodb/local.env
```

I really don't care about dynamodb and do not want to go through the setup for it.

Is it possible to ask `docker-compose` to ignore errors in other sections of yml file?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the yaml file will need to be 'valid', even if you are only spinning up one container within it.  In this case, because the env file doesn't exist, compose won't be able to finish parsing the file.  You could probably comment out problematic lines in the config file, and be able to start what you need.

Comment: Thx for your comment! Please kindly turn it into an answer so I can upvote & accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the yaml file will need to be 'valid', even if you are only spinning up one container within it.

In this case, because the env file doesn't exist, docker-compose won't be able to finish parsing the file.

You could comment out problematic lines in the config file, by starting the line with a # symbol, and be able to start what you need.